# Calculate the total distance travelled with CLLocation and swift

Tags: swift, swift3, core-location, cllocationmanager, distance

I've ben trying to calculate the total distance travelled in the following way:

```
if startLocation == nil {
            startLocation = locations.first
        } else {
            if let lastLocation = locations.last {
                let distance = startLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)
                travelledDistance += distance
                startLocation = lastLocation
                print( "\(startLocation)")
                print( "\(lastLocation)")
                print("FULL DISTANCE: \(travelledDistance)")
                print("STRAIGHT DISTANCE: \(distance)")
            }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is just a simulator issue but in the beginning, the distance between 2 locations(that calculate the straight distance) are very large(around 1.5km) and eventually they become a lot more accurate(+- 15m). 
Could anyone help solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should discard location updates that are not within a desired accuracy.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that maybe the first couple recordings aren't very accurate however I am running the locations off a gpx file in the simulator so it would be safe to assume that those location values are accurate?